# Creating a simple website MSI installer in WIX

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I've been trying to adapt the following WIX XML to create an MSI to install a web site.

I'm pretty new to this but WIX has quite a step learning curve, so I've gotten as far as the code snippets below indicate.

It won't compile at the moment as I get this error:

**Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixComponentGroup:C_WebAppContent' in section 'Product:*'**

All I want to do is the following.

Install the web site to D:\websites\website
Set up the virtual directory
Set up the App Pool

and that's it... Where am I going wrong with the below?

Product.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" 
     xmlns:iis="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" 
     xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">

  <!--NEVER EVER EVER EVER CHANGE THE UPGRADE CODE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! -->
  <?define UpgradeCode="176df50b-d3aa-4f25-ae7b-2098a6b881b2" ?>

  <Product Id="*" 
           Name="MdxWebsite" 
           Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" 
           Manufacturer="RBS" 
           UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />

    <!-- This includes our properties that implement the "Remember Property" pattern -->
    <?include Configuration.wxi ?>

    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <MajorUpgrade AllowDowngrades="no" 
                  AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" 
                  Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"
                  DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version of this product is already installed. Setup will now exit."/>

    <!-- Creating default directory structure (INSTALLLOCATION be override by user, but it starts in Program Files) -->
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
        <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="TheDefaultInstallFolderName">
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Feature Id="F_Content" 
             Title="Content" 
             Level="1" 
             Description="The website content" 
             ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION">
      <ComponentRef Id="C_RegistryEntries"/>
      <!-- The C_WebAppContent can either be generated by the WiX tool "heat", or a hand-crafted set of content, this component is not included in this example -->
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="C_WebAppContent" />
    </Feature>

    <Feature Id="F_IISWebsite" Title="IIS Website" Description="The IIS website and application pool" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="C_IISWebsite" />
    </Feature>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    <!-- Specify UI -->
    <UIRef Id="UIFlow" />
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Where is your component called 'C_WebAppContent'. This component is missing that is why it is throwing that error.

Comment: That's what im trying to generate, how would I go about in Visual Studio getting the web site project referenced harvested and then it's id for the harvested files? so I could then reference those for files for the id C_WebAppContent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to fix this by using the ID that was created by HEAT for the output in Visual Studio help in the in ..\obj\Debug folder